# Solution Explorer Search doesn't find controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, solution-explorer

[image]

Using Visual Studio 2013 with TFS and ReSharper, writing an MVC application, the Solution Explorer Search function sometimes finds the methods in my Controllers, and sometimes it doesn't.

- It always finds the actual files.
- It does not matter if I am in edit mode or run mode.

Does anyone have any insights into this?

In the picture above, it is showing the method inside the controller.

In the picture below, you can see that the Images folder appears, along with the Views and some other stuff, but the Controllers folder is not shown.
[image]

Comment: this usually happens when I have accidentally set wrong criteria. E.g. only search current document or project. Only search certain file extensions, or use regex. Take a screen shot of your search panel and post it.

Comment: Started happening to me as well after installing VS2012 Update 5. [FRUSTRATION INTENSIFIES]

Comment: I am at a loss for why sometimes the method shows and sometimes it does not.